# removeEventListener for anon function in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, addeventlistener

I need to disable an onClick action until an animation has stopped. Animations can be started by 4 different buttons - all need to be deactivated.

I use a listener to pass params to the function that will initiate the animation which is why I use an anonymous function in the add listener:

```
up.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, 
    function(event:MouseEvent):void
    { 
        revealSpinner(event,51.42,1,spinner);
        event.currentTarget.removeEventListener(event.type, arguments.callee);
    },
    false, 0, true);
```

I also have a self calling remove listener, but really I need to remove the listener from the other 3 buttons.

I have also tried naming the anonymous function but that didn't work:

```
up.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, 
    myFunc = function(event:MouseEvent):void
    { 
        revealSpinner(event,51.42,1,spinner);
    },
    false, 0, true);

// somewhere else in my app
up.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myFunc );
```

Edit:
each of the 4 buttons has to pass different parameters to the revealSpinner() method
revealSpinner(event,51.42,1,spinner);
revealSpinner(event,51.42,-1,spinner);
revealSpinner(event,120,1,anotherMC);
revealSpinner(event,120,-1,anotherMC);

Answer (score 1):

You can use the event.currentTarget parameter as you have already shown but in a callback function. Just use a switch statement to set the parameters depending on how the function was called:

```
function setupButtons()
{
    ...
    this.up.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, cbButtonClick, false, 0, true );
    this.down.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, cbButtonClick, false, 0, true );
}  

function cbButtonClick( event:MouseEvent ):void
{ 
    switch( event.currentTarget )
    {
        case this.up:
            revealSpinner(event,51.42,1,spinner);
            break;
        case this.down:
            revealSpinner(event,999999,1,spinner);
            break;
    }

    event.currentTarget.removeEventListener(event.type, cbButtonClick);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use anonymous functions.  If you define a handler for each button you can still pass your custom parameters, but you'll have a properly defined listener that can be removed at any point:

```
up.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, upButtonHandler, false, 0, true);

function upButtonHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{ 
    revealSpinner(event,51.42,1,spinner);
    up.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, upButtonHandler);
}


down.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, downButtonHandler, false, 0, true);

function downButtonHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{ 
    revealSpinner(event,999.999,999,spinner);
    down.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, downButtonHandler);
}
```